# Node.js/Nowjs - Moving a sprite and keeping track of time server-side

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

I am using node.js and express, and I am calling server-side functions and syncing variables using nowjs. Suppose the user is drawn as a sprite on the canvas. His x,y coordinates are kept server-side in a "position" array.

Server-side:

```
position = { x : 0; y : 0 } 

updatePosition = function (a,b) 
{ 
  playerPosition.x += a; 
  playerPosition.y += b; 
}
```

Client-side:

```
if keypress('right'){ updatePosition(32,0); }
```

These are pseudocode. When the user presses the 'right' button, the server-side "updatePosition" function is called, which adds 32 (pixels) to the x-coordinate of the "position" array. This array is then shared with the client, and the new position is drawn on the canvas using client-side function.

Suppose I don't want to draw the sprite at the new position instantly. I want to play a walking animation that gradually moves the sprite 32 pixels to the right, and takes say 1 second to complete. I might implement it this way:

1. User presses the 'right' button.
2. The animation starts playing client-side.
3. updatePosition is called server-side as usual.
4. When animation on the client finishes, check if the final position client-side matches the coordinates stored server side.

When the user presses the 'right' button/key, he cannot repeat the keypress until 1 second later. The 1 second long "walking" animation has to complete and final position checked with the server-side coordinates before he can press 'right' again to move his sprite.

Question: How do I keep track of the 1 second server side? I can't do it client-side because the user will be able to hack his client to reduce the animation time.

Is the solution to "timestamp" the position array? E.g. position = { x : 0; y : 0, time: 0 }. If the user presses the 'right' button again, the server would check to see if the last position update was greater than 1 second ago. If less than 1 second, the server ignores it.

Comment: I would say you're doing it wrong. Such feature should only be implemented on the client-side. Your server code should not have to be modified for client-only features. For example, why not just calling `updatePosition` when animation finishes? Or interrupting the animation if the users clicks another time? Or simply stacking them? Is this a critical function so you?

Comment: I need the animation to take 1 second to complete. Users might hack their client to finish the animation in 0.5 seconds instead. When there are multiple users, the hacker would be able to move twice as fast as everyone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not simply storing a "lock" in the user session?

```
session.editLock = new Date().getTime();
```

When another edit is triggered by the client, just:

```
if(session.editLock && new Date().getTime() - session.editLock > 1000) {
  // Return error
}
```

Modifying the position object doesn't feel right to me. A position object is meant to store position, not time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can players hack the session to "unlock" himself? I am using express + passportjs to handle log in sessions.

I suppose the crux is using "Data().getTime()" server-side to keep track of time (timestamp the position updates). Where I am keeping the timestamp (session or position array) shouldn't matter?

Comment: No, the session is strictly server-side, and users can't tamper with session data. That's why it is used for authentication purposes. Technically, where you store the timestamp does not make any difference. But when hesitating about where to store some data, I'd always advise you to ask yourself about what makes the more sense. In this case, I'd definitely say that storing this in session really makes more sense than in the position data, which I'd expect to store... a position. Not a timestamp.

Comment: Nice. I think I will be using sessions to store the "lock". AND still timestamp the position. The reason is that I plan for multiple users to move sprites on my website, and interacting (e.g. animation when they collide). The position array might be updated with the final position server-side but client-side the sprite is still "walking" there.

One last question: Session seems to be a handy place to dump all the variables related to the player. E.g. If I decided to have a "health" that reduces each time the sprites collide, I can store the "health" variable in the session. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well, yes, it could be temptating and handy to store everything in the session. But you should keep in mind that sessions are not meant to be persistent. If your server storing the session data crashes, you might loose all the data. For a lock or authentification info, this is not a big deal. But for health, I would store this in the player's record in your database, if, of course, your application is database driven. If this info is only valid throughout the session and must not be persisted, yes, storing it in the session looks perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I just realize that the "lock" is essentially a timestamp. Perhaps I'll define a "userInfo" array, keep the both the position array and timestamp/lock value in it, and store "userInfo" in the session. I don't need these data to persist, but thanks for the tip I'll keep it in mind. I guess this is resolved. :)